# How can I copy data of structure into string?

Tags: c, string, structure

My structure is defined like this:

```
typedef struct Game {
    // game board
    char board[4][4];
    // current score
    int score;
} GAME;
```

How can I copy data from `game->board[r][s]` into a string `char b;`?

I have already tried this

```
strcpy(b,game->board[r][s]);
```

and this

```
 b=game->board[r][s];
```

The whole thing should do the following. Let's say that board[r][s]=A and board[r][s+1]=A.

After

```
char b,b1;
strcpy(b,game->board[r][s]); //not working
b1=game->board[r][s+1]; //not working

if(strcmp(b,b1) == 0)
{
    game->board[r][s+1]=game->board[r][s+1] + 1;
    game->board[r][s]=' ';
}
```

`game->board[r][s+1]` should be B. I know it's not finished yet. But I've got stucked.

Comment: `char b = game->board[r][s];` ??

Comment: note that `char b` is _not_ a string.  It is a "C character".

Answer (score 1):

'char b' is not a string - you would need this to either be 'char b[10]' or 'char *b'.

Once you have a string you could use [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) to copy the data from board[i] to b (or simply loop through them both).

For a more in-depth answer please provide some more context. What data is in board, and why are you copying it to b? What format do you want it to end up in? What have you already tried?

Note that if you set b with char *, you will need to [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) space for it before copying into it.

Comment: @Bobrys I still don't understand what  you'd like to see in your 'b' variable. Could you expand on what you mean by "b1=game->board[r][s+1]; //not working". Assuming [r][s+1] is a valid index, this should set b1 to the contents of that cell.

Comment: I wanna see in b variable content of game->board[r][s]

Comment: @Bobrys what are 'r' and 's'? Is this in a loop? What are you using 'b' for?  As bgfriend0 commented above, 'char b = game->board[r][s];' will do that.